# find store address on google maps within 15,30, and 50 miles using sql server query

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
@Latitude decimal(10,7),
@Longitude decimal(10,7),
@Radious decimal(10,2)

SELECT 
    ID, StoreName, StoreNo,       
    Address, City,
    Latitude, Longitude,
    (StoreName + ' ' + Address + ' ' + ZipCode + ' ' + State) as wholeaddress ,        
    SQRT(POWER(Latitude - @Latitude, 2) + POWER(Longitude - @Longitude, 2)) * 62.1371192 AS DistanceFromAddress 
FROM 
    tb_BS_StoreList 
WHERE 
    (ABS(Latitude - @Latitude) < @Radious) 
    AND (ABS(Longitude - @Longitude) < @Radious) 
ORDER BY 
    DistanceFromAddress
```

I use this stored procedure to find `store address` from table. I have already saved address, latitude and longitude in my table.

I send the radius on miles like `0.15` for `15` miles `0.3` for `30` miles but it's not returning result accurately. Please help.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I think this condition is wrong

> where (ABS(Latitude - @Latitude) < @Radious) 
>    AND (ABS(Longitude - @Longitude) < @Radious)

Try to use your DistanceFromAddress 
like this

> where SQRT(POWER(Latitude - @Latitude, 2) + POWER(Longitude - @Longitude, 2)) * 62.1371192 <@Radious